# Conflict between javascript and media queries

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I have made a script in order to modifiy my navbar when the user scrolls down.
I need to change a top value for my responsive menu button (which is `#menu-btn`)

After executing the script, my `ul` takes the class name `scrolled` and all the styles are applied except the `top` value which is fixed at 19px because of the media query.

This is what I don't understand. Is it like a priority on the media query somehow ?

Thanks for your help.

**Here is my nav**

```
<ul class="nav justify-content-center">
        <li><a id="menu-btn"><img src="img/menu-icon.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="logo-lc" class="nav-link active" href="index">
                <img src="img/logo-lc.svg" width="60px" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" id="li-services">
            <a class="nav-link" href="services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" id="li-creations">
            <a class="nav-link" href="creations">Créations</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" id="li-presentation">
            <a class="nav-link" href="presentation">Présentation</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" id="li-contact">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**Here is my media query for small screen**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav li{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav li a{
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .nav #li-services, .nav #li-creations, .nav #li-presentation, .nav #li-contact{
    display: none;
  }
  #menu-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    left: 19px;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #menu-btn img{
    max-width: 32px;
    z-index: 99;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

**And here is my script for the scrolled navbar**

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    $( ".nav-link" ).css( "font-size", "18px" );
    $("#menu-btn").css("top", "8px");
  }
  else {
    $( ".nav-link" ).css( "font-size", "23px" );
    $("#menu-btn").css("top", "19px");
  }
}

$(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
    var $nav = $(".nav");
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
  });
});
```

Comment: Are any of your styles getting applied? Check your console for errors. In your HTML, I don't see an element with a class name of `ul`.

Comment: Try to use vscode and take a look at console in your browser

Comment: 1. your code has multiple errors, there is no `getElementByClassName` it should be `getElementsByClassName`. and top of it you are trying to query an element with tagname with `getElementsByClassName` which doesnt work. 2.`getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName` will return a HTMLCollection, so you neeed to use array notation to select the element 3. you are trying to query multiple tags with `getElementsByTagName` which doesnt work... try using `document.querySelector`

Comment: It looks also you'r using jQuery so why JS in this basic things?

Comment: I removed the getElementsByClassName line and the menu-btn top value is still unchanged

Comment: Read ajai Jothi's comment again.

Comment: I updated the scrollFunction() and it runs correctly. Thanks for your help and sorry about my big mistakes and confusion.